# I can't identify this kanji ( kanji 当ても)

Tags: kanji, readings, word-requests, reading-comprehension

[image: help]

I've decided to read manga in japanese again, I left it for a couple of years so now I'm out of practice and in need of help. It must be a really simple one but still I want to understand without feeling ashamed for ask.

Comment: it is 額 ^^ https://jisho.org 's radical search is very useful for this sort of thing

Answer (score 5):

The kanji is 額{ひたい} (forehead), and the word is [額当て](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E9%A1%8D%E5%BD%93%E3%81%A6), read ひたいあて.  It's a forehead protector made of a metal plate worn on a cloth band.

You should be able to find it in your dictionary under the 頁 radical, or with a multi-radical search feature like Janusz mentions above in his comment.  If I had to look it up, I would most likely use handwriting lookup.  However you want to do it, you'll most likely need to look up lots of characters in the future, so you should familiarize yourself with kanji dictionaries and get used to looking them up quickly.